# Radgrid to Excel import after applying data validation on certain columns

Tags: telerik, export-to-excel, radgrid

I am using Telerik:radgrid with all columns types as 'Telerik:GridBoundColumn'. I need to export radgrid's data to excel file after applying data validation. Before exporting this file to client i would like to convert some of Excel columns fields into drop down lists. So that user might be forced to select data from drop down list instead of entering wrong data. What would be the best way to accomplish this task ?

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using an Html based export format (default one) the TextBox
>   text should be exported automatically. Regards the issue with
>   extorting RadComboBox control a possible solution is to add a Label
>   which will be hidden, but its Text will be the same as the selected
>   value of the RadComboBox. This way when you export the grid you will
>   switch the visibility of both controls and the exported document will
>   contains all the ComboBox values.

[Source](http://www.telerik.com/forums/export-radgrid-template-column-with-combobox-and-textbox)